# Recursively fetch records in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In my application one can find all team reportees of an employee by doing the following

```
User.where(primary_reporter: "some unique code of a user")
```

where primary reporter is the user whose team reportees one needs to fetch.

However I am trying to now recursively find the reportees of the said user and the reportees of his team members forming a hierarchical chart. Have not been able to find anything there.

My user model is this:

```
class User
  has_many :reportees, lambda { |user| includes(:actor).where [" . 
  (users.status = 1)"] }, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 
  'primary_reporter'
end

class Actor
  has_one: user
end
```

I am using postgres for the database

Comment: I think you can use a recursive query as described here http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/

Comment: Depending on your usage, did you look at the Nested Set model?

Comment: You can also use the [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#migrating-from-plugin-that-uses-parent_id-column) gem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement hierarchical implementation in postgres with rails then you can try `ltree` extension in postgres where you can make use of indexes (for fasten querying) as well. Also we have ruby gem, using this gem we can easily make queries.

References

Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ltree.html

Rails: https://github.com/cfabianski/ltree_hierarchy